# 3-way handshake and get request using scapy in python

Tags: python, sockets, scapy

I am using scapy for 3-way handshake and sending get request and receiving response. But I am getting a TCP packet in response with FIN flag set. I am expecting HTTP packet with requested page. Where am I going wrong ?

```
import sys
import socket

from scapy.all import *


# 3 way handshake
ip=IP(dst="webs.com")
SYN=TCP(sport=80, flags="S", seq=100, dport=80)
SYNACK=sr1(ip/SYN)

my_ack = SYNACK.seq + 1
ACK=TCP(sport=80, flags="A", seq=101, ack=my_ack, dport=80)
send(ip/ACK)

# request 
PUSH = TCP(sport=80, dport=80, flags='PA', seq=102, ack=my_ack)
payload = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: webs.com\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\nCache-Control: max-age=0\r\nUpgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1\r\nUser-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/58.0.3029.110 Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36\r\nAccept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8\r\nAccept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8\r\n\r\n"
reply= sr1(ip/PUSH/payload, timeout=10)
```

Wireshark result

[image: wireshark result]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your machine is sending a RST packet.  The RST packet is being sent by the kernel.
http://www.packetlevel.ch/html/scapy/scapy3way.html.

Try dropping the RST packet through iptables.
`iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags RST RST -s 192.168.43.119 -j DROP`

Comment: What is the reason for the RST packet sent during 3-way handshake?

Comment: Cause Scapy creates it own socket and bypasses the whole TCP/IP stack. The kernel doesn’t know about it and correctly Sends a RST packet in response to the second part of the handshake cause it didn’t request the connection.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're using a wrong sequence number when you send the request:

```
PUSH = TCP(sport=80, dport=80, flags='PA', seq=11, ack=my_ack)
```

`seq` should be 101, not 11, since you used 100 for SYN. Changing it seems to fix the problem.

Also if you do not change the source port in your tests and you do not shut down the TCP connection properly or do not wait for 120 seconds between your tests the server might consider the new packets to belong to a previous connection and send something that you do not expect in response (depends on the state of the server connection).

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my silly mistake. Actually I am using 102 in my actual code as seq number. But still I am just getting a packet with reset flag set every time. What may be the possible issue ?

Comment: Sorry, there was a mistake in my reply, you should actually use sequence number 101 on the first data frame, not 102 - since ACK packets do not contain payload (I've corrected the mistake). Using that I do get a reply (301 redirect) from the server. So the code works. Of course the server never gets an ACK or connection shutdown so it keeps re-trying to send the response for a while. I hope your question was not an attempt to use SO users to DDoS the site :)

Comment: I am still not able to do it. I have added wireshark packets in the question. Please have a look. My machine is sending a Reset packet. I am not able to understand.

Comment: Do you run this on Windows or Linux? Does the script print any warnings when you run it? The RST packet is generated by something other than your script. Maybe there is a firewall involved? Which blocks port 80. Try using a different source port (it does not have to be 80 at all) and check your firewall settings.